# Overlay WMS layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I have three to four layers (shapefile data) in GeoServer, and I have to have all of them to make a map of a city.  However, so far I can only create a map with only one layer by writing

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
var build_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {layers: 'building'}
```

If I add more layers by writing

```
var population_wms=...
var road_wms =...
map.addLayers([build_wms,population_wms,road_wms]);
```

then I can choose only one of these layers (in layer switcher) to be displayed in the browser.

How could I solve this problem? Do I have to set one of the layer as the base map and add other layers by using var vector? Then how can I convert those layers to .json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a WMS layer is considered to be an opaque base layer in OpenLayers. This means you can only see one at a time, to change this set `isBaselayer: false`

So for example:

```
  var build_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {layers: 'building'}
            {isBaselayer: false, transparent: true});
```

However you will need at least one baselayer to be set or the map will not be initialised properly.

*Actually that's not completely true but it's close enough for this question*

Comment: I just add layers together as follows:                      var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map",
            allOverlays: true

            });                                           var city_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "City", "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {layers: 'vagar_alla',srs: 'ESPG:3021'... });
                
            var road_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Roads",
                    "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {layers: 'vagar_alla',
                    srs: 'ESPG:3021'... });